# Data Analysis using SQL/Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am working on the Data Analysis using SQL on Kaggle.

[https://www.kaggle.com/dimarudov/data-analysis-using-sql/comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6Z5.jpg)

However, I am not sure why tables is returning a blank database.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r"C:/Users/ksumm/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Projects/Euro Soccer/database.sqlite"
database = path + 'database.sqlite'

conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

tables = pd.read_sql("""SELECT *
                     FROM sqlite_master
                     WHERE type='table';""", conn)
```

Output image:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6Z5.jpg)

Comment: You have `database.sqlite` repeated in file name.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
database = path + 'database.sqlite'
```

You can directly use `path` since that path already contains path to sqlite database.

modified code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r"C:/Users/ksumm/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Projects/Euro Soccer/database.sqlite"

conn = sqlite3.connect(path)

tables = pd.read_sql("""SELECT *
                     FROM sqlite_master
                     WHERE type='table';""", conn)
```

OR

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r"C:/Users/ksumm/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Projects/Euro Soccer/"
database = path + "database.sqlite" 

conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

tables = pd.read_sql("""SELECT *
                     FROM sqlite_master
                     WHERE type='table';""", conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = r"C:/Users/ksumm/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Projects/Euro Soccer/database.sqlite"
database = path + 'database.sqlite'
```

You're appending the database name to the database name.  If you look on  your disk, you may find a file named

`C:\Users\ksumm\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Projects\Euro Soccer\database.sqlitedatabase.sqlite`

To avoid that in the future, the Python SQLite module has a slightly odd way to *not* create a database if it doesn't exist when you open it.  The [connect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) method accepts a URI, and the URI accepts parameters.  When the filename is correct, this will do what you want:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('file:%s?mode=rw' % database, uri=True )
```

If `database` does not describe an existing file, the `rw` mode causes the function to fail, raising a *sqlite3.OperationalError* exception.